# VoIP app on Windows 10 Mobiles got exception The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation

Tags: c#, voip, windows-10-mobile, windows-phone-voip

I build a VoIP app on WP 8.0 SDK and deploy it on Microsoft Lumia 535 running Windows 10 Mobile Insider Preview Build 10586.36. Sometimes I make an outgoing call but it failed, tracing my log it show the reason is The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation(HResult = -2147019873) when I call this function [RequestNewOutgoingCall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.phone.networking.voip.voipcallcoordinator.requestnewoutgoingcall.aspx) of class [VoipCallCoordinator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.phone.networking.voip.voipcallcoordinator.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

After got that exception, my app can't start any outgoing calls even when I go to the homescreen, kill app and restart app many times. However my app can request new incoming call successfully, showing incoming call screen and active call when pressed answer.

Right now I still don't know how to reproduce this bug. Does anyone have any ideas for why request new out going call got this exception and how to working around this bug.